# Need to extract 4 spaces of text before the occurrence of a word that appears in a column in a df, and may occur several times per row

Tags: regex, r, substring

I need to extract text (4 characters) before the occurrence of the word "exception" per row in a column of my dataframe. For example, see two lines of my data below:

1. MPSA: Original Version (01/16/2015); FMV Exception: Original Version (04/11/2014); MM Exception: 08.19.15 (08/19/2015)
2. MPSA: Original Version (02/10/2015); FMV Exception: Original Version (12/18/2014); MEI FMV: V3 (12/18/2014); MEI FMV: updated (11/18/2014); Meeting Material exception: Original Version (04/21/2014);

As you can see, "exception" occurrs more than one time per line, is sometimes capitalized and sometimes not, and has different text before. I need to extract the "FMV", "MM", and "ial" that come before in each case. The goal is to extract as a version of the following (comma separating would be fine but not needed):

1. "FMVMM"
2. "FMVial"

I am planning on making all text lower case for simplicity, but I cannot find a regex to extract the 4 characters of text I need after that. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need `strsplit`, `substr` and `nchar`:

```
t1 <- "1.MPSA: Original Version (01/16/2015); FMV Exception: Original Version (04/11/2014); MM Exception: 08.19.15 (08/19/2015)"

t2 <- "2.MPSA: Original Version (02/10/2015); FMV Exception: Original Version (12/18/2014); MEI FMV: V3 (12/18/2014); MEI FMV: updated (11/18/2014); Meeting Material exception: Original Version (04/21/2014); "

f <- function(x){
  tmp <- strsplit(x, "[Ee]xception")[[1]]
  ret <- array(dim = length(tmp) - 1)
  for(i in 1:length(ret)){
    ret[i] <- substr(tmp[i], start = nchar(tmp[i]) - 3, stop = nchar(tmp[i]))
  }
  return(paste(ret, collapse = ","))
}
f(t1) #gives "FMV , MM "
f(t2) #gives "FMV ,ial "
```

Avoiding the loop would be better but for now, this should work.

---

Edit by Qaswed: Improved the function (shorter and does not need `tolower` any more).

---

Edit by TigeronFire:

@Qaswed, thank you for your guidance - the answer, however, poses another problem. t1 and t2 are only two lines on a dataframe 10000 rows long. I attempted to add the column logic to the function you built a few different ways, but I always received the error message:

```
"Error in strsplit(BOSSMWF_practice$Documents, "[Ee]xception") : non-character argument"
```

I tried the following with reference to dataframe column BOSSMWF_practice$Documents:

```
f <- function(x){
  tmp <- strsplit(BOSSMWF_practice$Documents, "[Ee]xception")[[1]]
  ret <- array(dim = length(tmp) - 1)
  for(i in 1:length(ret)){
    ret[i] <- substr(tmp[i], start = nchar(tmp[i]) - 3, stop = nchar(tmp[i]))
  }
  return(paste(ret, collapse = ","))
}
```

**AND**:

```
f <- function(x){
     BOSSMWF_practice$tmp <- strsplit(BOSSMWF_practice$Documents, "[Ee]xception")[[1]]
     BOSSMWF_practice$ret <- array(dim = length(BOSSMWF_practice$tmp) - 1)
     for(i in 1:length(BOSSMWF_practice$ret)){
        BOSSMWF_practice$ret[i] <- substr(BOSSMWF_practice$tmp[i], start = nchar(BOSSMWF_practice$tmp[i]) - 3, stop = nchar(BOSSMWF_practice$tmp[i]))
     }
     return(paste(ret, collapse = ","))
 }
```

I attempted to run the function on my applicable column using both function setups

`BOSSMWF_practice$Funct <- f(BOSSMWF_practice$Documents)`

But I always received the above error message. Can you take your advice one step further and indicate how to apply this to a dataframe and place the results in a new column?

---

Edit by Qaswed:
@TigeronFire you should have added a comment to my answer or editing your question, but not editing my question. To your comment:

```
#if your dataset looks something like this:
df <- data.frame(variable_name = c(t1, t2))

#...use
apply(df, 1, FUN = f)
#note: there was an error in f. You need strsplit(x, ...) and not strsplit(t1, ...).
```

Comment: apologies - I was trying to leave a comment before instead of edit, but the comment box kept closing whenever I hit the [return] button; and it still does.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it ended up giving me an error that I investigated and cannot find a fix for. Here is what I plugged in:

BOSSMWF_practice$Func <- apply(BOSSMWF_practice, 27, FUN = f)
I assume that the [1] in your apply example indicates the 1st column, and the column I need to investigate is the 27th:

Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I thought that meant that there are null values when using the function, which breaks it, so I tried to address with na.rm=TRUE without success. Apologies for asking again, but any recommendations?

Comment: No. The `1` in apply says: "the function will be applyied to every *row* of your object (here `df`)". If it were a `2` it would mean to apply it to every *column* (see the manual by typing the R-command `?apply` into your R-console). If you want it wo apply to every row of the 27th column use `apply(BOSSMWF_practice[ , 27], 1, FUN = f)`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help - I was able to use the information you provided to get the answer I was looking for. However, still could only use the function "f" on a vector rather than a dataframe. When I used the "apply": function on a multi column dataframe as you suggested, it always resulted in the error message "dim(x) must have a positive length". I searched for a way to correct it, and tried dozens of choices, but could not find the fix. Can you give some guidance on why this was the case as a final piece of guidance?

Comment: Did you try `apply(df, 1, FUN = f)`? If not, what then did you do?

Comment: Maybe you have to reduce `df` to only those varaible that come under Deliberation. By this I mean using `apply(df[, c("variablename1", "variablename7", "variablename25")], 1, FUN = f)` if the only relevant variables are named "variablename1", "...7" and "...25".